# Change all external links in Wordpress with Hidden Referrer href.li

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

so I want all the external links on my website to be redirected to href.li in order to hide the referrer info.

So, how is it implemented? currently I build a website with **WordPress** and I've been looking for a plugin that can change the referrer info but it's out of date.

Example:

```
Original External Links : https://google.com
Href.li hidden referrer : https://href.li/?https://google.com
```

Comment: Let's see your jQuery code attempt.

Comment: you want to change all `<a>` tag's like to rferrer links right?

Comment: Ya i want to change all a tag

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by the `jQuery` and for that purpose you have to install a plugin in you wordpress. [Plugin Link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/)
In code just loop throug all `<a>` and concatinate the url.
for concatination
`referrer_link + orinal_link`
And for changing link

Comment: can you tell me to tag the jquery?